# Convert model created in 3DS Max 2011 to work in 3DS Max 2009

Tags: 3dsmax

I have 3DS Max 2009 w/ Vray 1.5 sp2 , and i got a model that was created in 3DS Max 2011 Vray 2

I cant afford to upgrade , and since this is purely a hobby for me , i was wondering if the model could be converted to work in my current version. If so , how difficult would it be and how much would i expect to pay to have someone do the conversion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to open it in 3dsmax 2011 and then export it to FBX or another format that 2009 can read back in. Also try and export the material library from 2011 and see it if can be loaded into 2009.

Then most likely you have to assign the materials and all that again.

If you can import the material library then you can make a script that exports the material names from 2011 with object names to a text file, then you can read that back in 2009 and have it automatically assign the materials back on the objects.